# How to use linear-gradient with weasyprint?

Tags: css, weasyprint

I'm trying to render a pdf from HTML with weasyprint.

I need to use linear-gradient as a background color.

But when I try to use:

background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #da208b, #4b77f2 51%, #6bd2b5);

I get a pdf without a background-color. (html is rendered correctly)

So how can I do it in weasyprint? I see in documentation that the linear-gradient should be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use background css property instead of background-color:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.bad {
    background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #da208b, #4b77f2 51%, #6bd2b5);
}
.good {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #da208b, #4b77f2 51%, #6bd2b5);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bad">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum..</p>
</div>

<div class="good">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```